# Including typedef enum from header file in another header file

Tags: c, enums, typedef

I keep running into an issue while trying to include an enumeration from one header file in antoher.
The environment I am working in is embedded C using IAR Embedded Workbench.

I have a header file for dedicated enumerated types named "enums.h"

```
#ifndef ENUMS_H_
#define ENUMS_H_

typedef enum
{
    SET,
    SCHEDULE,
    EXECUTE
}action_type_t;

#endif
```

and a header file for a parser named "parser.h"

```
#ifndef PARSER_H_
#define PARSER_H_

#include "enums.h"
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    action_type_t action;
    uint16_t nbytes;
}Message;

#endif
```

In parser.c I include the header as

`#include "parser.h"`

When I compile this, I get the error "identifier action_type_t is undefined"

What am I doing wrong here? I am stumped at this point.

Thank you

Comment: You need `;` after each member in the `enum` definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `enum` definition is missing commas, your `parser.h` uses `uint16_t` while having failed to include `<stdint.h>` and, to be extra pedantic, your include guard macro is encroaching on the reserved namespace because it starts with `_` and a capital letter.

This should work:

*enums.h*:

```
#ifndef ENUMS_H_
#define ENUMS_H_

typedef enum
{
    SET,
    SCHEDULE,
    EXECUTE, /*the last comma is optional*/
}action_type_t;

#endif
```

*parser.h*:

```
#ifndef PARSER_H_
#define PARSER_H_

#include "enums.h"
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    action_type_t action;
    uint16_t nbytes;
}Message;

#endif
```

Comment: I believe `_t` names are reserved too, at least in POSIX. Under ISO C, I think it's more complicated but the it might be wise to simply avoid them altogether.

Comment: Is comma after last member i.e. EXECUTE in enum really required? I have tried without comma. It's working fine.

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaBellamkonda The last one is optional.

Comment: Thank you. The actual source code has the commas in the enum, but they were somehow removed in copying the text over. I have tried removing the first underscore in the #define, and tried renaming my typedef to something without "_t" at the end, but to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who answered, I figured I would come back and close this one.
It turns out I had an identically named, but empty header file included in my project...

Next time i'll be better about looking in my own backyard first before asking others.

However PSkocik did provide a working example, and his code compiles perfectly for anyone who stumbles into this thread!